# trying to select random data PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to select random strings. 
The problem is it returns the same value for each row. Why is that and how to fix?

```
SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT chr((48 + round(random() * 59)) :: integer) 
FROM generate_series(1,40)), '') AS string FROM generate_series(1,10);

Output:
|  string   |
| duplicate |
| duplicate |
| duplicate |
...
```

10 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres overoptimizes the subquery.  I think this is an error, because it is missing the fact that `random()` is volatile.

A simple fix is a correlation clause:

```
select (select string_agg( chr(48 + (random() * 59)::int), '')
        from generate_series(1 ,40)
        where gs.i is not null
       ) AS string
from generate_series(1, 10) gs(i);
```

I rewrote the logic a bit, so it is simpler.  There is no need to use arrays for what you want to do.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4cd3566cdb334ae5b2cbdebb6061ca17) is a db<>fiddle.